# Tkinter label grid_propagate doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to ad a label to a tkinter app, showing the procedure status, while doing something.

**I don't want my window to stretch to follow the label size**, so I used grid_propagate to apply this flag to the label and it's master, but this seems like is not working and the grid is moving, following the label size.

Here an example, following the same structure of my original program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def buttonManage():
    
    label1.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    threading.Thread(target=labelManage, name='LabelThread').start()

def labelManage():

    while not label1.winfo_ismapped():
        # Wait for graphic interface manager to draw, before removing resizing propagation from container frame
        time.sleep(0.1)

    label1.master.grid_propagate(False)
    label1.grid_propagate(False)

    for n in range(1, 100):
        label1.configure(text=label1.cget('text') + 'a')
        time.sleep(0.1)

    label1.master.grid_propagate(True)
    label1.grid_propagate(True)


window = Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(window)

mainFrame = ttk.Frame(tabControl, padding='10 10 10 10')
optionFrame = ttk.Frame(tabControl, padding='10 10 10 10')

tabControl.add(mainFrame, text ='Backup')
tabControl.add(optionFrame, text ='Options')
tabControl.grid()

button = ttk.Button(mainFrame, text='Backup', command=buttonManage)
button.grid(columnspan=2, ipadx=70, ipady=20)

label1 = ttk.Label(mainFrame, text='')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your problem is caused by `time.sleep` which is not compatible with `tkinter`. Try using `window.after(delay, function)` instead.

Comment: The grid is not moving, it is being expanded.  The window is not expanding during the label update, it is expanded after the label update.  It fulfills your requirement and so what is your issue actually?

Comment: i don’t want that the grid to expand. I don’t want o to give to the label a fix width, but I want that it get the maximum width as the frame dimension. I cannot give it a dimension related to the frame width, because the grid width is in characters while the frame is in pixel. The funny thing is that if I use pack instead of grid, the label don’t expand more then the frame dimension.